# ViewPagerIndicator not snapping or displaying pager contents all of a sudden

Tags: user-interface, android, android-viewpager

This is a wierd problem.

This will be a terrible question because I have little to no information.

About two days ago I had the ViewPagerAdapter working just fine. I could swipe and it would switch between views as defined by the adapter.

However, all of a sudden (not by itself, I'm sure I did something) the TitlePagerIndicator doesn't snap to the headings and doesn't display any content. By not snapping I mean that if I drag to the left, the title will sit at 3/4 of the screen instead of snapping to the side and displaying the next page (screenshot below).

I have debugged and instantiate item is called and a proper view is returned.

However, when I open the app I'm getting a lot of warnings like these:
VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3015: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.getAlpha ()F
VFY: unable to resolve direct method 3011: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;. (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;I)V
VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2965: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.setAlpha (F)V

I'm assuming this is a problem with my imports, but everything compiles just fine, I have the ViewPagerIndicator as a library project, as well as Sherlock.

Here's my adapter code:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements TitleProvider {

private static String[] titles = new String[] { 
    "My Klinks", 
    "Received Klinks"
    };

private final Context context;

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public String getTitle(int position) {
    return titles[position];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return titles.length;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View pager, int position) {
    TextView t = new TextView(context);
    t.setText("WheeeE");
    return t;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View pager, int position, Object view) {
    ((ViewPager) pager).removeView((TextView) view);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);
}

@Override
public void finishUpdate(View view) {
}

@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable p, ClassLoader c) {
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void startUpdate(View view) {
}
}
```

And here is my activity code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.main );

    // set up the slidey tabs
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter( this );
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById( R.id.viewpager );
    TitlePageIndicator indicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById( R.id.indicator );
    pager.setAdapter( adapter );
    indicator.setViewPager( pager );

    // set up the action bar
    final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();

    ab.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ad_action_bar_gradient_bak));
}
```

[image: Title indicator not snapping]

Comment: well for starters, have you tried cleaning the project and restarting eclipse?

Comment: Many times. I had a problem a couple days ago with my android support jars not matching up between projects all of a sudden. So I updated them all with the latest one from my Android source folder. I'm pretty sure that's when the issue started. However, when I switched them all back to the one that's supplied on the ViewPagerIndicator git source, no dice. I'll try using the one that is included in the Sherlock git source and see if that does anything. Could using a different version of support package cause the issue?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like something that might cause problems. I'm not sure if it is very likely that you'll get a helpful response here if that's the case lol... I don't see anything wrong with your code. It must be a problem with your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone else gets the same problem:

In instantiateView: don't forget to attach your new View to the ViewPager:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View pager, int position) {
    TextView t = new TextView(context);
    t.setText("WheeeE");
    ((ViewPager)pager).addView(t);
    return t;
}
```

The current version of instantiateItem gets a ViewGroup instead of a View, the solution should be the same.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer on the assumption that it's right :) I can't verify because I changed my method. However, this looks like it would have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well after a couple days of banging my head against a wall I've come to the conclusion that my ViewPagerAdapter was the problem.

I simply created a dynamic fragment and created a subclass of FragmentPagerAdapter instead and now it works just fine...